# Function is not getting called on clicking the button

Tags: php, html, frontend

This code is in first.php

```
function fas(){
    echo "fuction";
    echo "Anything";
}

if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    fas();
}
?>
```

Code in second.php

```
<?php 
include 'first.php'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type= "submit" name = "btn"> click this</button>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking the button, function fas is not getting called. What's the issue?

Comment: You have a submit button, but nothing _to_ actually submit ... This needs a `form` around the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the button in a `form` tag, then the button like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
<button onclick="function_name()">Submit</button>
```

The second one is going to call the function directly, and not go to a separate link like a form would.